# Edit image into circle shape and insert into another image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have `image1`, I would like to make that image circle shape and then insert it into `image2`. How to do it using swift? I can't do this with photoshop or other image editing tool, because my `image1` will may be different every time.

**EDIT:** This what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Flower is `image1`.

**EDIT 2:** What I have tried and kind of works:

```
let image2 = UIImage(named: "RedPin")
let newSize = CGSizeMake(image2!.size.width, image2!.size.height)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)

image2!.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height))

let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image1)
var layer: CALayer = CALayer()
layer = imageView.layer

layer.masksToBounds = true
layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(65)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

// decrease top image size
roundedImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(10,10,45,45), blendMode: .Normal, alpha:1.0)

let createdNewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

Yet `image1` is more a square with rounded edges and in general image seems to be low quality. Here is what that function above does:

[image]

**EDIT 3:** [Toucan](https://github.com/gavinbunney/Toucan) library is great at creating rounded images (`let roundedImage = Toucan(image: newImage).maskWithEllipse().image`), however final image version still looks blurry. Why's that?

Comment: Try to set the `image1?.layer.cornerRadius`. What do you mean by `then insert it into image2`  ? and are they both of type `UIImageView` ?

Comment: The thing is I want to use custom marker in Google Map SDK. My `image2` is a custom shape marker (let's say a triangle) and my `image1` is some photo/image that will be placed inside that marker. End result should be, that depending on where the marker is placed it will have a different image inside.

Comment: and you have forgot to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I did not forgot, I did not included because I don't know where to start exactly. Should I do this with Layers? Core Graphics? Any suggestion where to start  would be appreciated. 
Although I did some more googling and found something similar to what I need. I've added code and an example how image would look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Set image like this with rounded corner with same code like you.

```
func UserImageForAnnotation() -> UIImage {

        let userPinImg : UIImage = UIImage(named: "pin_user.png")!
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(userPinImg.size, false, 0.0);

        userPinImg.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: userPinImg.size))

        let roundRect : CGRect = CGRectMake(2, 2, userPinImg.size.width-4, userPinImg.size.width-4)

        let myUserImgView = UIImageView(frame: roundRect)
        myUserImgView.image = UIImage(named: "pic.png")
        //        myUserImgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        //        myUserImgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        //        myUserImgView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        let layer: CALayer = myUserImgView.layer

        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = myUserImgView.frame.size.width/2

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myUserImgView.bounds.size, myUserImgView.opaque, 0.0)
        layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        roundedImage.drawInRect(roundRect)


        let resultImg : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return resultImg

    }
```

Which gives me exact result what I want in my pin image.

[image: user pin image]

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of able to achieve similar result using Toucan library, however final result looks blurry, low quality. I tried your code, although I've adjusted scale `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(userPinImg.size, false, **1**)` and the photo inside looks bad. Why's that? Because simply reducing photo size, should not downgrade its quality so drastically